# odd glitch in normal map

Tags: normal-map

I am new to Blender and am building some basic shapes and trying different texture methods. In this case I am modelling a rock and when I plug in the normal map I get the following weird line.

[image: Weird Line]

the normal image looks like this:

[image: Normal Image]

and the output from the Normal map node looks like this:

[image: Normal Map Output]

Note that it doesn't appear when the normal map is off

[image: Normal off]

Here is my node map:

[image: Node Map]

with a zoom on my normal map data:

[image: Normal Map Zoom]

The shape is a basic low poly shape with 2 subsurf and 2 displacement modifiers. I am using the Object data from the TextureCoordinate node instead of unwrapping, as I've seen many people do that without issues.

[Here is a link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wtqjs3twnn3t7yf/Rock.blend?dl=0) to the blend file.

any help would be appreciated!

Thanks Dan.